# eclipse rcp 4 - customize workbench

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4, workbench

I am working on a rich client (RCP 3.7) which depends on some quite large customizations made in (My)WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents 
With the new RCP (to which I need to update) this method does not get called anymore and in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP#Contributing_to_the_Model it is stated that I need to make all my customizations in the application model. Unfortunately I did not yet find useful documentation on how to do exactly that. All the tutorials I found so far "only" concentrate on how to use the application model to embed Parts, Menus, Handlers and so on. 
Does anybody have any hints on how I can as much of my old customization (MenuBar, CoolBar, StatusLine ...) as possible or at least where I can find some more infos than the quite empty-looking eclipse-wiki pages?

Thank you in advance!

Addition:

My CoolBar is in reality a composite containing a coolBar and some other stuff. Am I right in the assumption that I cannot simply add a TrimMenu in my application model and then set a view on to it?

Comment: The Application Model includes the menu bar and cool bars (called Trim bars). The status line is just a trim bar at the bottom of the main window.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) covers most of Eclipse e4 development (or buy the book referenced on that page which expands the tutorial)

Comment: thank you greg-449 - but since I have some logic in there as well I would really prefer another way than manually transferring it to the application model